# Character gets stuck / freezes in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a racing game with pygame (not finished) by following a tutorial on youtube. The code works totally fine, except when I pressed the arrowkey and pressed the opposite of that arrowkey really quickly, the race car gets stuck until I let the key go and press the key again. Is there any way to fix that?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


carImg = pygame.image.load('BlackCar.png')

def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x, y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 0

    x += x_change
    y += y_change


    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x, y)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Alright, try to remove the code for KEYUP event, see what happens and let me know. Let's delete above comments for brevity.

Comment: you may use `x_change -= 5` `x_change += 5` in `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` and then it should work better. It will "cumulate both arrows and it will "remeber" previous arrow when you release other arrow. Now when you release second key then it set  `x_change = 0` and it doen't remeber second key.

Comment: it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x_change -= 5` and `x_change += 5` in `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP`

When you keep left arrow then it move left, when you press also right arrow (both are pressed) then it doesn't move but if you release one of arrow and still keep other then it move again (in correct direction)

```
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change += 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change -= 5
```